# How do you add a batch of registry entries to group policy?

Tags: group-policy, windows-registry

For example I want to add Google Search as the default search service to IE.  The seven registry entries are below.  Do I really have to enter each one individually under *User Configuration > Preferences > Windows Settings > Registry*?  Is there an easier way to add registry entries into group policy?

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchScopes]
"DefaultScope"="{3B236023-DA3B-4545-8218-B0D402D2AA87}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchScopes\{3B236023-DA3B-4545-8218-B0D402D2AA87}]
"DisplayName"="Google"
"URL"="http://www.google.com/search?q={searchTerms}&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:{language}:{referrer:source}&ie={inputEncoding?}&oe={outputEncoding?}"
"ShowSearchSuggestions"=dword:00000001
"SuggestionsURL"="http://clients5.google.com/complete/search?q={searchTerms}&client=ie8&mw={ie:maxWidth}&sh={ie:sectionHeight}&rh={ie:rowHeight}&inputencoding={inputEncoding}&outputencoding={outputEncoding}"
"OSDFileURL"="http://www.ieaddons.com/en/DownloadHandler.ashx?ResourceId=813"
"FaviconURL"="http://www.google.com/favicon.ico"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mention, using GPP to configure a large number of keys/values can be painful. There are a few options that immediately come to mind:

1. Put in the GPP registry settings piecemeal. Slow, and kinda un-fun to configure.
2. Use `regedit /s your.reg` to slurp in the registry settings file.  Not great but it works.
3. Use `reg /add` to write each key/value. Like above but doesn't require separate .reg file.
4. Write an ADM/ADMX to customize the key/values. We chose this route.

This [Microsoft support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918238) details the particulars of creating ADM/ADMX files specifically for managing search providers.

Comment: Thanks jscott.  Looks like we're going to go with option #4 as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can define multiple entries with a custom ADMX file. 
Here's a guide on TechNet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753471(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Place the registry values in a *.reg file then run the reg file using a logon script.